# How to accomplish the following effect using CSS

Tags: html, css

> Blockquote

How do I accomplish the background behind the text "This week's inspiration" attached in CSS.

I have the following CSS:

```
.title-wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(53,65,76,0.51) 0%, rgba(53,65,76,0.1) 100%);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 12.5px 0 12.5px 12px;

}
```

It works but at the end it gets transparent so the gradient doesn't span the full image.

[image]

Comment: Can you post full css class ? And html portion concerned ?

Comment: Added the CSS. Please check

Comment: As @Math said, would be helpful to see the HTML as well.

Comment: We need to see parents divs/spans. How and where is your image defined in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this (remove the opacity attribute):

```
background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(53,65,76,0.51) 0%, rgba(53,65,76,0.1) 100%);
```

Comment: How is this different than the background-image rule in the original question?

Comment: He has update his code it was `background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(53,65,76) 0%, rgba(53,65,76,0) 100%);opacity: 0.51`